# Key vault group for each services

Tags: azure-keyvault

Can we have groups inside same keyvault? Like each groups inside associated with secret keys of different microservices instead of having different key vault for each microservices

Answer (score 0):

There are no groups inside a key vault.  You could mark each key/secret with a tag, but it's not going to show in the portal in any particular order and there's no differentiation wrt security.

Comment: What would you suggest in this scenario ? To go with tag or have separate keyvaults for all microservices?

Comment: Or can you share any link where I can check how to add tags to secrets

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/about-secrets#secret-tags

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-resources?tabs=json

Comment: Thankyou @Matt Small

Comment: If my answer was correct and helped you, please mark it as the answer.